# How do I set the BillingTier in the BigQuery Ruby API?

Tags: ruby, google-bigquery

Some of my queries are returning `billingTierLimitExceeded` error and troubleshooting it lead me to documents telling me to change the configuration for my query job.

I found the `configuration.query.maximumBillingTier` in the REST API but not for Ruby client library.

How do I set `configuration.query.maximumBillingTier` using the Ruby SDK?

Comment: There is a GitHub PR for this, but it hasn't been merged yet: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby/pull/1432

Comment: It seems this parameter has been deprecated. There are no more details about pricing tiers on a pricing page: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#on_demand_pricing

Answer (score 0):

To run the query at a higher pricing tier, pass a new value for `maximumBillingTier` as part of the query request, the same way as you pass other properties. See reference [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.query).

For example, you could do something like `configuration.query.createDisposition` or `configuration.query.allowLargeResults`

It should be noted that the `maximumBillingTier` is a positive integer that serves as a multiplier of the basic price of $5 per TB. See reference and more detailed info [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#high-compute).

You could also achieve this from within bq command line:

```
USAGE: bq.py [--global_flags] <command> [--command_flags] [args]
```

Alter the `job_property` global flag as needed:

> --job_property: Additional key-value pairs to include in the properties field of the job configuration; repeat this option to
>   specify a list of values

Comment: The question was how to do it using the Ruby API, which doesn't include this option yet (see my comment to the question.)